# Any way to retrieve deleted phone contacts?

Tags: contacts, data-recovery

My wife has a cheap Android phone (Telstra branded, Blade A5 2020-T, Android version 9). For some unknown reason, for the last few weeks many names were duplicated in her Contacts list. So today she went through and deleted the duplicates. But when she went back to Contacts, both copies had been deleted! So she has lost a dozen or so contacts. Is there any way to get them back?

A couple of other points:

- A number of web pages say to enter Contacts, click the left hand side button, and find the Recycle bin. But on this phone, there is no Recycle bin there.
- System says that "Cloud backup" is on, but we can't find anything under her Google account. But maybe we are not looking in the right place.

Comment: Have you tried https://support.google.com/contacts/answer/7280886 -> scroll to "Recover deleted contacts"?

Comment: Are the contacts saved/synced to Google Contacts (maybe check on the Contacts app)? Otherwise, "Cloud backup" might mean [Google Drive Backup](https://drive.google.com/drive/backups), but it doesn't seem to include contacts.

Comment: @Robert - I saw that and it was no help, unfortunately; because it is about Google Contacts, not the contacts stored locally on one's phone.

Comment: @AndrewT. Google Contacts contains email contacts (from her use of gmail) but no phone numbers. Google Drive Backup is a nice find, but like you said it does not seem to include contacts.

Comment: We have found a workaround though: she can go through her message history and restore the deleted contacts manually.

Answer (score 1):

Data recovery of deleted contacts depends upon how the data is stored in the device, if your contacts are stored inside the phone’s internal storage, they will be deleted permanently. If the contacts are stored inside the sim card and is deleted, contact your service provider to recover the data. If your contacts were synced with Google Account, it can be easily recovered from Google Contact App. Following are some DIY techniques.

**To recover contact from Google account:** Open Google Contact App > Fix and Manage > Select Bin Folder (Deleted Contacts will appear) > Click three dots on top left corner > Select or Select All > Click Recover

**To recover contact from Undo Feature:** Open Google Contact App > Settings > Scroll down and tap on Undo changes > Select the time frame > Tap Confirm > Ok

Answer (score 0):

If your contacts were saved to Google Contacts, you could try to dump the data from chrome://sync-internals.  If the contacts are still present server-side, you can also attempt to take a [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout?pli=1) backup to get them.